# TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function - Can not solve error

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I found this topic often but I'm still not able to get the problem solved. This is my page viewed in the browser (it includes header, navigation via php). The `$.datepicker.setDefaults` seem to work just fine, however the `$(function() { $( "#dateFrom" ).datepicker(); } );` throws the error. I've tried to use document ready function as well as the `$.noconflict()` function.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navigation.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footer.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
      dateFormat: 'dd.mm.y'
    });
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
      dayNamesMin: ['So', 'Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa']
    });
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
      monthNames: ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"]
    });
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
      inline: true
    });
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
      showOtherMonths: true
    });
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
      firstDay: 1
    });
  </script>
  <title>[...]</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <a href="index.php">
      <span class="title">[...]</span>
      <a href="[...]" class="logo" title="Startseite"><img src="./img/logo-son.png" alt="" /></a>
    </a>
    <div id="authenticatedUser">
      <br /> Eingeloggt als: </div>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="navigation">
      <a href="index.php">
        <div class="nav_eintrag">
          Startseite
        </div>
      </a>
      [...]
    </div>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#dateFrom").datepicker();
      });
    </script>
    <div id="content">
      <h1>[...]</h1>
      <form name="[...]" action="[...]" method="post">
        [...]
        <input type="text" class="searchInput" name="dateFrom" id="dateFrom" placeholder="Startdatum"> [...]
        <input style="float:right" type="submit" name="action" value="Absenden">
    </div>
    </form>
    <br>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables/datatables.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/datatables.js"></script>
    <div class="exportButtons">
      <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
    <table id="AssignmentTable">
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>Area ID</th>
          [...]
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <pre>Array
           [...]
          </pre> </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var table = $('#AssignmentTable').DataTable();
    table.page.len(25).draw();

    new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
      buttons: [{
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        customize: function(xlsx) {
          var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];

          $('row c', sheet).each(function() {
            $(this).attr('s', '50');
          });
        }
      }]
    });
  </script>
  <div id="footer">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I shortened the page a bit so it's less garbage to read.

Comment: I placed your code in a runnable snippet and `datepicker` seems to be working fine. It is throwing an error about `DataTable` though, as you haven't included that library at all

Comment: I included it after the submit form. So my guess would be that datepicker and DataTable dont like each other. Do you got any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Isn't it just a typo and it's `dataTable`and not `DataTable`. The line below with `new $.fn.dataTable ... ` seems to point in that direction as `$.fn` is just an alias for the prototype of jQuery objects...

Comment: I can assure you that dataTables and datepicker work side by side quite happily. The error is implying that you've not included a library properly somewhere.

Comment: Thats why I copied the browser view of the site. Since that shows all libraries that are included on the page. But as I said, I cant find the problem.

Comment: @adz5A it's not a typo, .DataTable is right in that case and works pretty well. About the $.fn as long as that does not impairs the datepicker it should be fine.